# pivot of a 3d model outside its mesh after importing into Unity3d

Tags: unity

as you can see, the pivot is outside my mesh. I want to use the pivot for rotating around, for that I need to set the pivot to the real "rotating point". I know that there's the SetPivot script, but it only works with pivots inside meshes.

This mesh is part of an object which contains several meshes, I created it with Wings3d. The problem appears with .obj  and .3ds as file extension.

[image]

1.How can I fix this?

2.Is there a possibility to define a second pivot which can be used in scripts to "rotate around"(maybe a vector3 which can be set in "Designer")?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101571/is-there-a-way-of-moving-the-transform-of-an-object-relative-to-its-geometry/101587 - you may find the answer to that one useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try switching it in unity interface from pivot to center.

[image]

or you could create an empty game object and make your model a child of it and then change the position of your model that is parented to the empty game object, this will make your empty game object the pivot of your model. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it some hackish way in Unity, by wrapping with a parent Transform, but the root of the problem is with the model. If you can't fix it with Wings, run it through Blender or something before importing.

Answer (score 0):

You may fix this in Blender, maybe you can fix it up in Unity but I dont know that

Here it is the steps to fix it in Blender:

Open your model with Blender
Select your mesh object and press Shift S to set the Z Cursur on the. center of your mesh and change pivot point from left panel by seting the Origin, if you can not see the panel press Shift T.

Export your mesh again possibly to an Obj or anything you like.